# Python - peewee - Debugging statements - where are the errors logged

Tags: python, mysql, try-catch, peewee

I have just started to use peewee in python. But as i am saving table data using .save() function. There is an error in the line. and control does not go to the next line.

Just wanted to know how can know what the error is. Although i have narrowed down to the line as below

```
     try:
        with database.transaction():
            driver = Driver()
            driver.person = person
            driver.qualification = form.getvalue('qualification')
            driver.number = form.getvalue('phone')
            driver.license = form.getvalue('issu')
            driver.audited_by = 0
            print "this line prints"
            driver.save()
            print "this one does not print"
            print "Success"

    except:
        print "Error"
```

I have used print statements i was able to figure out the error in in the line driver.save(). But how to check what exactly is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is specified in the `peewee` documentation [here](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/database.html#logging-queries).

Answer (score 10):

Peewee logs queries at the DEBUG level to the peewee namespace, so you just have to configure logging as desired.  Per the [docs](https://peewee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peewee/database.html#logging-queries):

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('peewee')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score -1):

In the future, you should also include the traceback when you're asking for help debugging an error. The traceback tells you, as best as it can, exactly what went wrong.

If you want to do some debugging, you can check out `pdb` (or `ipdb` if you use iPython):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: there was no traceback in this case, else i certainly would have added. It was just puff blank.

Comment: You can get the traceback by removing the `try/except` block I would imagine.